# Ruby gem for creating a doc file from database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doc

I have a table which has column of type mediumtext.
now i have to write a script to fetch that field from my table and store them into a word document.
Is there any rails plugin or gem available to convert mediumtext field into a word document.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that .doc file format isn't that great, and changed quite a bit over time hence why there aren't any ruby libraries for it.  You could try interfacing your ruby script to one of the Java libraries out there that does it.  Take a look at this project http://poi.apache.org/, as well as the ruby bindings for it.